# Some images can be loaded, but some can't loaded with texImage2D

Tags: java, opengl

I am using following java code to load a image as a texture and display on the screen. But i found that all the image i edited with `gimp` can't be loaded, but some images downloaded from web can display normally on the screen.

```
    private void loadTexture() {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.b, options);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, bitmap, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the image isn't corrupted ? Also does image format matches texture format ?

Comment: @MichaelIV Using what tools can i check the image format?

Comment: Any image editing program should give you ability to see the pixel format of the image.I am not familiar with Gimp but in Photoshop when I save the image I select the format to save to so I already know what it is when using it with OpenGL textures.